# I have example source for accessing GCM sever without application sever and I try to convert winapi source

Tags: java, android, winapi, google-cloud-messaging

I develop an android app with a desktop program that works with winapi, and I tried to access google GCM sever without application sever. I found a great example, and it works very well. But I need access GCM sever via winapi application. I also develop android app and that helps me understand how to work this example, but I can't convert for winapi java and winapi is so defferent, and i've never used something like a winapi http connection such as Get, Post.

...somebody help me.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;

public class TestSender {
static String gcmURL = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";
static String gcmRegID = "device register ID";
static String gcmAuthToken = "GCM sever Access Key";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        sender(gcmRegID, gcmAuthToken, "Test MSG");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void sender(String regId, String authToken, String msg)
        throws Exception {
    StringBuffer postDataBuilder = new StringBuffer();
    postDataBuilder.append("registration_id=" + regId); // register ID
    postDataBuilder.append("&collapse_key=1");
    postDataBuilder.append("&delay_while_idle=1");
    postDataBuilder.append("&data.msg=" + URLEncoder.encode(msg, "UTF-8"));
    byte[] postData = postDataBuilder.toString().getBytes("UTF8");
    URL url = new URL(gcmURL);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    HttpsURLConnection
            .setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new FakeHostnameVerifier());
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-formurlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
            Integer.toString(postData.length));
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + gcmAuthToken);
    OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
    out.write(postData);
    out.close();
    conn.getInputStream();
    System.out.println("postData : " + postDataBuilder.toString());
    String reponseLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            conn.getInputStream())).readLine();
    System.out.println("responseLine : " + reponseLine);
}

private static class FakeHostnameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear for me. In windows, if you want to access to the Internet(http), you can use WinInet or WinHttp api sets.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383630(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382925(v=vs.85).aspx